# Draw multiple set of barplot + lineplot using seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart

I'm trying to draw **multiple sets of barplot + lineplot** from a dataframe using **seaborn** like the one below (I've already succeeded in drawing one):

[image]

Here you can find the dataframe used to produce it => [dataframe](https://github.com/StefanoPuccini/Stack-Overflow)

What I'd like to achieve is this kind of graph (which I have already succeeded in creating) but ***repeated for all the possibile product families*** inside a speicifc product basket ('family' is a drill down level of 'product basket')

Thanks a lot for anyone who will help me. I've tried some looping but probably I'm just doing it wrong.

Here is the code that I've used to draw the above graph:

```
#select a family
df_perc2=df_perc.query('family=="WORKWEAR & PROTECTIVE CLOTHING"')

#set common axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax_twin = ax.twinx()

#set boxplot general aspect
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(30, 10)
sns.set_style("white")

#ship_to_count bars
barplot = sns.barplot(data=df_perc2, 
                  x = 'orders_count', 
                  hue = 'SF_type', 
                  y = 'ship_to_perc',
                  palette = "Set2",
                  ax = ax)
#cumulative % line
lineplot = sns.pointplot(data = df_perc2,
                     x = 'orders_count',
                     hue = 'SF_type',
                     y = 'running_perc',
                     palette = "Set2",
                     marker ='o',
                     ax = ax_twin,
                     legend = False)

#set tick stiles for x and y axis
barplot.set_xticklabels(barplot.get_xmajorticklabels(), fontsize = 18)
barplot.set_yticklabels(barplot.get_yticks().round(2), size = 18)
lineplot.set_yticklabels(lineplot.get_yticks().round(2), size = 18)

#set dynamic title
barplot.set_title('% Ship Tos by # orders for '+''.join(df_perc2['product_basket'].unique())
              +
              ' - '
              +
              ''.join(df_perc2['family'].unique()), fontdict = { 'fontsize': 30}, y = 1.05)


barplot.get_legend().remove()

#set constant line at 90%
plt.axhline(y=0.9, color='g', ls=':', lw=4, label='90th percentile')
lineplot.legend(loc='center right',fontsize='22')
```